# APACHE GEODE MULTIPLE EVENT LISTERS

Tags: events, geode

Quick question regarding this scenario.
I have 2 PCs.  I have a locator and server running on both PCs in the cluster.
I have 1 region in this example and its replicated.

Basically, when an entry is entered (PUT) in to the region, I want to publish a JMS message with the data for downstream processes on a different systems to consume.

If i have a CQ or event listener running on both PCs, how can I have only 1 JMS message published?

Will both CQ, OR event lister(s) be executed on both PCs if the entry is PUT into PC1, and then gets replicated to PC2?

Answer (score 0):

Well if you have 2 event listeners running at the same time that both register interest to a given set of keys (or all keys) in the region then yes both listeners will fire. But if you have only 1 listener (client) running then the locator(s) will “bind” it to 1 server not both so in that case although the server data is replicated between 2 servers the (client) listener is only notified by the server it’s directly connected to.

To test this I would write a JUnit test to start a client listener, put some data in the region and check it only fires the once. With your locator(s) and server(s) already up and running.

Comment: Thanks.  I just wanted to make sure there was nothing I could do to prevent this in the above scenario.  Basically trying to figure out the auto fail over issue.  For example, if PC 1 goes down, the messages would then get published via PC2 listener.  Perhaps creating a function would be better?  So the client doing the "PUT" action then calls a "PUBLISH" function?   I will try some different things and let you know what I finally used.  If you have any thoughts on what I am trying to implement, please feel free to give your advice.

Comment: I am not sure how to fail over a pair of listeners on different boxes. To my mind you would install the same listener on the 2 boxes but only run it on 1 box as active. If active listener box goes down that would throw errors, monitor alerts and so on. Then you would manually start up the other listener on the other box… in that sense it’s not really a Geode question it’s a how to run active, passive, services question. 